# xarray: applying ufunc to month+day groups of dask based Dataset

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray, dask-distributed

I have a function that I'd like to apply along the time axis for each combination of month & day of a dataset, eg. to all time slices that have `month=1` and `day=1` over all years (and so on).

My current solution is to loop over the combinations, subset the dataset, apply the function and persist the result on the dask cluster:

```py
from distributed import Client
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

client = Client()


# fake function
def fun_along_time(x):
    return x*2

# testdata
x = xr.tutorial.load_dataset("air_temperature")

# time dimension needs to be single chunk
x = x.chunk({"time":-1, "lat":10, "lon":10})

timeindex = x.time.to_index()

for month in timeindex.month.unique():
    for day in timeindex.day.unique():
        xsel = x.sel(
            time=np.logical_and(x.time.dt.month == month, x.time.dt.day == day)
        )
        
        xres = xr.apply_ufunc(fun_along_time,
                              xsel,
                              input_core_dims=[["time"]],
                              output_core_dims=[["time"]],
                              dask="parallelized")

        xres = xres.persist()
        
        # some downstream tasks following
```

While this approach works, it does not seem very elegant and it calls `persist` repeatedly which is hard on the scheduler (and a bad practice?).

To make it work for the scheduler I've tried persisting the arrays together using `client.persist`, which worked OK but doesn't seem to be efficient either, and waiting for each array to finish persisting then computing the downstream tasks before moving on top the next iteration - this works too with obvious downsides.

So I'm wondering what would be a better way to achieve this, keeping in mind that this needs to scale well with `dask`.

I've looked into `groupby` and `map` but I don't think it works well for me as it generates a ton of `dask` tasks and messes with the chunksize which generates all kinds of issues itself.

I though about adding a new dimension / coordinate layer with `month`/`day` which I can then use for `map`/`apply_ufunc` but I cound't wrap my head around it.